# Not sure what this notation means.

Tags: notation

$f|_A(x)\rightarrow 0$

I know that "|" means  "or" or "such that"

I'm not sure what the sub scripted set A means, I'm pretty sure the arrow pointing to zero means that the expression on the left of the arrow approaches zero.

What I think it means is a function such that the set A are the inputs for x,  when inputted into the function the function approaches zero.

Comment: $f|_A$ is usually the restriction of $f$ to the set $A$ but it is not clear what $ \to 0$ means here.

Comment: `|` does nor mean ‘or’ in mathematics. This is a programmer notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea.  Given any function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and for any subset $A \subseteq X$, you can define/induce a function $f|_A(x)$, which is $f$ restricted to $A$.  It is as if you ignore the rest of $X$, and treat $A$ as the domain of $f$.